# What is the proper SMTP return code if an email server does not support the EHLO command but does support the HELO command?

Tags: smtp

I wrote a simple SMTP service and having issues receiving GMAIL. They insist on using the EHLO command and then using TLS. According to the https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1869 SMTP protocols standards they are suppose to issue a HELO command after an unsuccessful EHLO command. I am trying to figure out the proper SMTP return code if the SMTP service does not support EHLO command. I tried 500, 502 and 503 with limited success. Sometimes the email goes through, sometimes it does not.

What is the proper SMTP return code if an email server does not support the EHLO command but does support the HELO command?